# How to properly fetch for resources within a powerpoint using Add-in?

Tags: powerpoint, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I'm trying to create an Add-In for powerpoint that can grab all the texts in all powerpoint slides.

At the moment, I am able to grab the texts but i'm not sure if this is a proper way to do it. JS API.

```js
const presentation = context.presentation;

const slides = presentation.slides;

slides.load("items/shapes/textFrame/textRange/text");

await context.sync();

// forEach loop thru slides
```

there isn't a lot of documentation regarding this.

why does using "/" separated strings work but not comma-separated as in the docs?

does anyone have any resources they can share that has more explanations?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the right way.  To your other question - my understanding is that you use "/" to designate a path. Meaning, if you want to load all the tag values for all shapes in all slides, you would .load("items/shapes/tags/value").  If you just want to load the whole item, you use .load("items")

Im wondering if chaining the way you have done here is better than calling load("items") at each step, e.g.:
shapes = slides.shapes.load("items")
  for each shape...
    tags = shape.tags.load("items")
etc...